# Update table error code 1054

Tags: mysql

I want to update table `ospos_sale` value with new value that I selected but it cannot update.

Here is my sql code

`update ospos_sales set subtotal_amount = ( select * from (select sale.subtotal_amount-saler.subtotal_amount
from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler on sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id where sale.id=ospos_sales.id) as m2), total_discount = (select * from (select  sale.total_discount-saler.total_discount from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler on sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id where sale.id=ospos_sales.id) as m3), total_amount = (select * from (select  sale.total_amount-saler.total_amount
from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler on sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id where sale.id=ospos_sales.id) as m4),change_amount = (select * from (select  sale.paid_amount - sale.total_amount+saler.total_amount from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler on sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id where sale.id=ospos_sales.id) as m4) where ospos_sales.id= 10003`

Here is my table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE `ospos_sales`  (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `saletime` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fk_customers_id` int(10) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fk_users_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fk_locations_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `invoicenumber` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `quotenumber` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalsaledquantity` decimal(15, 3) NOT NULL,
  `subtotal_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `fk_dinnertables_id` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_discount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `tax_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `round_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `total_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `paid_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `change_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `salestatus` enum('draft','open','sale','return_request','returned','cancel_request','cancelled','cleared') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
  `paymentstatus` enum('unpaid','paid','partially','return') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unpaid',
.
.
.
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `invoice_number`(`invoicenumber`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `customer_id`(`fk_customers_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `employee_id`(`fk_users_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `sale_time`(`saletime`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `dinner_table_id`(`fk_dinnertables_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 36096 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

and table SaleReturnitem is

```
CREATE TABLE `ospos_salesreturn`  (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `returntime` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fk_customers_id` int(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_locations_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `fk_sales_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `returnref` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `subtotal_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `total_discount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `tax_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `total_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `paid_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `change_amount` decimal(25, 0) NOT NULL,
  `returnstatus` enum('draft','returned') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
  `fk_users_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `dels` enum('1','0') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cdate` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `mdate` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `syncfrom` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `syncmasterid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `customer_id`(`fk_customers_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `employee_id`(`fk_users_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 10 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

Error Message is :

```
> 1054 - Unknown column 'ospos_sales.id' in 'where clause'
```

Please help.

Comment: Does you table ospos_sales have a column called "id"?  Without seeing your database, it seems as though this is pretty straight forward.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: @Thomas yes, my table have column named id

Comment: @GordonLinoff i don't understand why it said like i don't have column name id but in my table already had this column

Comment: If you're okay with showing us, you could do a `show create table ospos_sales;` to show us the columns in that table and potentially why it would be failing for you.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your suggestion i already add table structure into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subqueries are giving ospos_sales an alias.  When you give a table an alias, you can no longer reference it using the table name, but you have to use that alias.

I assume your goal was to have it reference the update table, but being 2 levels in, it can't see it.

The easiest solution would be to simply put the ID in your subqueries instead of referencing the column.  Otherwise, you'll need to restructure the query.

If I didn't miss anything, it would be something like this.

```
update ospos_sales 
set 
    subtotal_amount = (select 
            *
        from
            (select 
                sale.subtotal_amount - saler.subtotal_amount
            from
                ospos_sales sale
            left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
            where
                sale.id = 10003) as m2),
    total_discount = (select 
            *
        from
            (select 
                sale.total_discount - saler.total_discount
            from
                ospos_sales sale
            left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
            where
                sale.id = 10003) as m3),
    total_amount = (select 
            *
        from
            (select 
                sale.total_amount - saler.total_amount
            from
                ospos_sales sale
            left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
            where
                sale.id = 10003) as m4),
    change_amount = (select 
            *
        from
            (select 
                sale.paid_amount - sale.total_amount + saler.total_amount
            from
                ospos_sales sale
            left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
            where
                sale.id = 10003) as m4)
where
    ospos_sales.id = 10003;
```

Comment: could you suggest the query structure please. because i don't want to put id number instead  subqueries

Comment: Why not?  Assuming you're using a prepared statement, it should flow with the ID you're already adding to the query.

Comment: because i would like to do like this where ospos_sales.id in (select fk_sale_id from ospos_salereturns)

Comment: thank you very much, i forget it long time ago. and sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much @Thomas for helping me to solved this issue 
now i got a solution that to modify my query and now my solution is  here

```
update ospos_sales up set 
subtotal_amount = 
( select a.subtotal_amount from (select sale.id, COALESCE(sale.subtotal_amount,0)-COALESCE(saler.subtotal_amount,0) as subtotal_amount 
from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
) as a where a.id = up.id
),

total_discount = 
 (select a.total_discount from (select sale.id,COALESCE(sale.total_discount,0)-COALESCE(saler.total_discount,0) as total_discount
  from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
  ) as a where a.id = up.id
    ),

total_amount = 
 (select a.total_amount from (select sale.id, COALESCE(sale.total_amount,0)-COALESCE(saler.total_amount,0) as total_amount
from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id 
) as a where a.id = up.id
),
change_amount =
 (select a.change_amount from (select sale.id, coalesce(sale.paid_amount,0) - coalesce(sale.total_amount,0) + coalesce(saler.total_amount,0) as change_amount
from ospos_sales sale left join ospos_salesreturn saler ON sale.id = saler.fk_sales_id
) as a where a.id = up.id)
where up.id in (select a.fk_sales_id from ospos_salereturns a )
```